# Ansible playbook copy failed - msg: could not find src

Tags: file, copy, ansible

I am new to ansible and I am trying to clopy a file from one directory to another directory on a remote RH machine using ansible.

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: root
  sudo: yes
  tasks:

  - name: touch
    file: path=/home/user/test1.txt state=touch

  - name: file
    file: path=/home/user/test1.txt mode=777

  - name: copy
    copy:  src=/home/user/test1.txt dest=/home/user/Desktop/test1.txt
```

But it throws error as below

```
[root@nwb-ansible ansible]# ansible-playbook a.yml -i hosts 
SSH password: 

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [auto-0000000190]

TASK: [touch] ***************************************************************** 
changed: [auto-0000000190]

TASK: [file] ****************************************************************** 
ok: [auto-0000000190]

TASK: [copy] ****************************************************************** 
failed: [auto-0000000190] => {"failed": true}
msg: could not find src=/home/user/test1.txt

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/a.retry

auto-0000000190            : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1   

[root@nwb-ansible ansible]#
```

The file has created in the directory and both the file and the directory has got permissions 777.

I am getting the same error message if I try to just copy already existing file using ansible.

I have tried as non-root user as well but no success.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Angel

Comment: Just now I read that "The copy module copies a file on the local box to remote locations." I was expecting it will copy a file from one location to another location on remote machine. Copy command looks for the file in local machine, and in my case it is not there. Hence the error message I am seeing is sensible.

Answer (score 5):

Luckily this is a simple fix, all you need to do after the copy is add

remote_src: yes

Answer (score 0):

If you have ansible >=2.0 you could use remote_src, like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: root
  sudo: yes
  tasks:

  - name: touch
    file: path=/home/user/test1.txt state=touch

  - name: file
    file: path=/home/user/test1.txt mode=777

  - name: copy
    copy:  src=/home/user/test1.txt dest=/home/user/Desktop/test1.txt remote_src=yes
```

This don't support to recursive copy.

Answer (score 0):

What is your ansible version? Newer version of ansible supports what you want. If you cannot upgrade ansible, try **cp** command for simple file copy. **cp -r** copies recursively.

```
  - name: copy
    shell: cp /home/user/test1.txt /home/user/Desktop/test1.txt
```